# TYPO3 FlexForm: how to disable field in inline element?

Tags: typo3, flexform

I have a TYPO3 plugin with a FlexForm. In the FlexForm I added relations to a foreign table. I now need to disable some of the fields of the foreign table. I can't do this via user rights since it's a question of context, not rights.

My FlexForm looks like this:

```
<settings.moreinfo>
    <TCEforms>
        <label>my label</label>
        <config>
            <type>inline</type>
            <foreign_table>tx_foo_domain_model_bar</foreign_table>
            <foreign_field>content_uid</foreign_field>
            <foreign_sortby>sorting</foreign_sortby>
            <maxitems>50</maxitems>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</settings.moreinfo>
```

I thought about `TCEFORM`, but have no idea how to address the field:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.foobar.general {
  settings\.moreinfo {
    # maybe here?
  }
}
```

Is there any possibility to disable a field via TSconfig or PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49303585/3946047) inspired me to the solution which finally solved my problem!

`foreign_types` was the solution I was looking for:

```
<settings.moreinfo>
    <TCEforms>
        <label>my label</label>
        <config>
            <type>inline</type>
            <foreign_table>tx_foo_domain_model_bar</foreign_table>
            <foreign_field>content_uid</foreign_field>
            <foreign_sortby>sorting</foreign_sortby>
            <maxitems>50</maxitems>
            <foreign_types type="array">
                <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                    <showitem>
                        title, link, --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access, hidden;;1, starttime, endtime
                    </showitem>
                </numIndex>
            </foreign_types>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</settings.moreinfo>
```

Answer (score 1):

in general you could disable flexform fields. the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html) states the possibility:

> Other properties also apply to flex form fields, in this case the full property path including the data structure key has to be set:
>   `TCEFORM.[tableName].[fieldName].[dataStructureKey].[flexSheet].[flexFieldName].[propertyName]`.
>   The `[dataStructKey]` represents the key of a FlexForm in
>   `$GLOBALS['TCA'][<tableName>]['columns'][<field>]['config']['ds']`. This
>   key will be split into up to two parts. By default the first part will
>   be used as identifier of the FlexForm in TSconfig. The second part
>   will override the identifier if it is not empty, list or *.
>   For example the identifier of the key `my_ext_pi1,list` will be `my_ext_pi1` 
>   and of the key `*,my_CType` it will be `my_CType`. See section Pointing to
>   a data structure of the TCA reference for details.
>
> Some properties apply to whole FlexForm sheets, their property path is
>   `TCEFORM.[tableName].[fieldName].[dataStructureKey].[flexSheet].[propertyName]`.

it could be problematic if you use `.` inside of identifiers.

Comment: `.` inside identifiers can be escaped using ``\``, e.g. `TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.powermail_pi1.main.settings\.flexform\.main\.confirmation.disabled = 1`