# Using Flexform-FAL Image in Typo3 10.x WITH editor

Tags: typo3, editor, fal, flexform

I wonder how to get the editor (image manipulation / crop) in Typo3 Flexform FAL image working. How to run up the FAL inside Flexform is not a big deal, but... how to get the editor? I din't found any solution, so it would be great getting some help.
the reason why I try it in flexform, is that I want ot stay on core functions without using flux and all that horrible stuff just to prevent version chaos....

here is a similar example of how I realsied it in Flexform.
[How to create a file upload field in flexform of a custom extbase extension in TYPO3 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615558/how-to-create-a-file-upload-field-in-flexform-of-a-custom-extbase-extension-in-t/61676728#61676728)

anyone got a solution get the editor running?

Found a solution
https://blog.wappler.systems/typo3-fal-image-in-flexform/

BUT: how can I use the cropped image in FE?

Comment: Are you talking about how to use crop variants? I am sure you can find an example of dat in the docs.

Comment: This was the first place of my search, just to avoid comments like "rtfm"